# How to Use Scite as default editor in Git

Tags: git, mate, scite

I'm using `git config --global core.editor "mate -w"` when using textmate. How do I set it to scite? I am not sure what `-w` or `-f` means. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-w` is a command line option, see `mate --help` what it means. You can probably just use `git config --global core.editor "scite"`, check `scite --help` for any options.

Answer (score 1):

I just set the editor like the following and it worked fine:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Scintilla Text Editor/scite.exe'"
```

On another machine I had to change the path:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/SciTE/scite.exe'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Textmate has a command line helper program called `mate` which is installed in your path. This line in config says run that program (which runs TextMate), and the `-w` flag means wait for the file to be closed before carrying on.

For Scite - it may have a command line tool and a flag that lets it behave the same way.